# Hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, you solve hypergeometric differential equation:

$x(x-1)y'' + [-\gamma + (\alpha + \beta + 1) x] y' + \alpha \beta y = 0$

for $\lambda = 0$ and now after gaining one solution, we search the other one by discussion over $\gamma$:

if $\gamma = 1$ then...(I know what)

if $\gamma \in \{2,3,....\}$, then....(I know what)

now if $\gamma \notin Z$ we have that we introduce the shift $y = x^{1-\gamma} z$ where z is another function of x, and when we differentiate this and substitute in first equation(one we are solving) after some transformation we shall get the hypergeometric equation for z and for changed $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, but I need complete work how, because I don't get it. So, just the hard work, I have final solution but no idea how to get it, I know it's just the computing, but I can't do it, please help!

Comment: Did you look on the Wikipedia page?  Your statements seem a little off.  The fact the you have a solution F(a,b,c;z) then you have another solution z^(1-c)*F'(a',b',c'....) should be easy to compute?  Just drop the new expression into the  DE and see if the prior condition DE(F) implies the new one.  If DE(F(a,b,c))->DE(z^(1-c')*F(a',b',c'))=0

Comment: More directly, try Luke - https://www.amazon.com/Special-Functions-Their-Approximations/dp/0124110371
Table 3.2 gives a list showing independent convergent solutions.   It's a rocky subject since integer parameters introduce special cases.  I will look it up if the Integer/NonInteger state of the parameters are known.